# Windows Phone 8.1: C# Callback with IList variable fails to cast to IVector

Tags: c#, c++, list, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a C# windows phone 8.1 Visual Studio (2013) project that declares an interface to a callback

```
    public interface ICallBack
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// The Child Callback must override this method and this will be fired when time comes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="files">The resultant files </param>
        /// <param name="code">Error code</param>

        void GotFileList(FileType type, IList<FileInfo> files, ErrorCode code);
    }
```

I have a C++/CX wrapper that implements it as follows:

```
ref class  CallbackImpl sealed : ICallBack
{
private:
    CallbackImpl(){}

public:

    virtual void GotFileList(FileType type, Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<Object^>^ files, ErrorCode code);
}
```

My problem is that on **Release** build, when C# calls ICallback::GotFileList

```
_callback.GotFileList(fileType, result as IList<FileInfo>, ErrorCode.EC_NO_ERROR);
```

it throws an exception `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid`. The exception refers to casting IList to IVector.

Debug is fine; meaning, i can add values to an internal IList and call ICallback::GotFileList and the IList values are in the C++ IVector without any problems.

I compared Release/Debug project properties (in all projects: C# core lib, C++/CX wrapper and C++/CX application) and did not find any difference that can explain the exception on Release build only.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the simple answer. Since the ILIst is of a proprietary data type `FileInfo` it fails to cast to IVector. As soon as i changed the interface function signature to `IList<Object>` instead of `IList<FileInfo>` (and the IVector respectively in the c++ wrapper), it all works.
Here is the new code snippet:

```
public interface ICallBack
{

    /// <summary>
    /// The Child Callback must override this method and this will be fired when time comes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="files">The resultant files </param>
    /// <param name="code">Error code</param>

    void GotFileList(FileType type, IList<Object> files, ErrorCode code);
}
```

c++ wrapper:

```
ref class  CallbackImpl sealed : ICallBack
{
private:
    CallbackImpl(){}

public:

    virtual void GotFileList(FileType type, Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<Object^>^ files, ErrorCode code);
}
```